# Installation failed during Oracle Application Express 18.2

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I installed Oracle Application Express Version 5.0 on Oracle Linux 6.9 with Oracle Database 11g and working perfect.

Now I want upgrade to 11.2 Version but I am getting this error during installation

[image]

Comment: I would try cleaning up the failed installation and trying again; if it fails again, contact Oracle Support.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to be on a minimum database version of 11.2.0.4 for APEX 18.2